# Помогите найти все пути log файлов в linux

Tags: linux, логирование

Интересуют все лог файлы в linux например в debian 10. Помогите дополнить список путей лог файлов. Пока мне удалось найти: 

Пользовательские
`/home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
/home/user/.cache/mozilla
/home/user/.atom`
И системные
`/var/log
/var/run/log` 
Просто хочу знать все данные которые собирает система о сессиях юзерах и самой себе

Comment: Какая конечная цель? Скрыть следы? syslog может по сети отправляться сразу же. Вот еще парочка: `~/.bash_history`, `~/.bash_history`

Comment: Вот еще. `/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-jira.log` `~/.kde/share/apps/kconf_update/log/update.log` `~/.PhpStorm2017.3/system/log/` `~/.mysql/workbench/log/wb.log`. Лог-файлы можно прописывать в конфигах. Поэтому на "не типичной" системе логи могут писаться куда угодно.

Comment: Вот [статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/selectel/blog/267833/) про аудит системных событий.

Comment: а ещё есть journald